# Update multiple columns based on one column Spark / Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataframe with a boolean column. If this column is set to true, I would like to change the values of various other columns. Is there a way to do this without having to do the following for every column that I need to update? - `.withColumn(<column that needs to change>, when(<boolean column is true>).otherwise(<column that needs to change>))`. Something along the lines of:

```
if (boolean column):
    col(<col1 that needs to change) = "val1",
    col(<col2 that needs to change) = "val2",
    ...
```

Comment: Just `map` the row

Comment: @sinanspd do you think you could provide an example?

Comment: `df.map(r => if(r.getBoolean(...)){ (... ,"val1", "val2", ...)}else{r})` Something along the lines of this. I will leave to you to look up how `map` and `get` works and figure out the rest

Comment: So the idea of mapping the row makes sense, but I'm not sure of an efficient way of modifying the values of the row

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. `map` takes a row and returns a new row with the updated values. The `tuple` I posted in the code above is the new Row with the updated values. You can not get anymore efficient than that

Comment: @sinanspd ah that makes sense. I guess I was looking for a way to not have to specify all values in the row. My row has dozens of fields, so I don't want to have to manually type out all the values that should stay the same. Ideally something like `row["field name 1 that needs to change] = "new value 1"`

Comment: Use `withColumn`